# MediaRecorder class Not Available in Electron APP

Tags: javascript, electron, web-mediarecorder

I was following Fireships' Electron tutorial to build a desktop capturer.
One thing I know is, as of now there is a huge difference between the version I used and his.
The only problem I am having is during the instantiation of the `MediaRecorder` class.
The class is not identified at all.

Is there a way I can fix it?

Render.js - Source Code

```
// Buttons
const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
const startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
startBtn.onclick = e => {
  mediaRecorder.start();
  startBtn.classList.add('is-danger');
  startBtn.innerText = 'Recording';
};
const stopBtn = document.getElementById('stopBtn');
stopBtn.onclick = e => {
  mediaRecorder.stop();
  startBtn.classList.remove('is-danger');
  startBtn.innerText = 'Start';
};
const videoSelectBtn = document.getElementById('videoSelectBtn');
videoSelectBtn.onclick = getVideoSources; 

const { desktopCapturer, remote } = require('electron');
const { dialog, Menu } = remote;

// Get the available video sources
async function getVideoSources() {
  const inputSources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
    types: ['window', 'screen']
  });

  const videoOptionsMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
    inputSources.map(source => {
      return {
        label: source.name,
        click: () => selectSource(source)
      };
    })
  );


  videoOptionsMenu.popup();
}

let mediaRecorder; //MediaRecorder instance to capture footage
const recordedChunks = [];

// Change the videoSources window to record
async function selectSource(source) {

  videoSelectBtn.innerText = source.name;

  const constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
        chromeMediaSourceId: source.id
      }
    }
  };

  // Create a Stream
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

  //Preview the source in a video element
  videoElement.srcObject = stream;
  videoElement.play();

  // Create the Media Recorder
  const options = { mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9' };
  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

  // Register Event Handlers
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  mediaRecorder.onStop = handleStop;
}

// Captures allrecorded chunks
function handleDataAvailable(e) {
  console.log('video data available')
  recordedChunks.push(e.data);
}

const { writeFile } = require('fs');

//Saves the video file on stop
async function handleStop(e) {
  const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks,{
    type: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9'
  });

  const buffer = Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer());

  const { filePath } = await dialog.showSaveDialog({

    buttonLabel: 'Save Video',
    defaultPath: `vid -${Date.now()}.webm`
  });

  console.log(filePath);

  writeFile(filePath, buffer, () => console.log('Video Saved Successfully!'));
}
```

Web Preferences - Index.js

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the render.js file, using `electron": "10.2.0`

```
const { desktopCapturer, remote, dialog } = require('electron');
const { writeFile } = require('fs');
const { Menu } = remote;

//Buttons
const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
const startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
const stopBtn = document.getElementById('stopBtn');
const videoSelectBtn = document.getElementById('videoSelectBtn');
videoSelectBtn.onclick = getVideoSources();

//Get all available video sources
async function getVideoSources() {
  const inputSources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
    types: ['window', 'screen'],
  });

  const videoOptionsMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
    inputSources.map((source) => {
      return {
        label: source.name,
        click: () => selectSource(source),
      };
    })
  );

  videoOptionsMenu.popup();
}

let mediaRecorder; //Mediarecorder instance to capture footage
const recordedChunks = [];

async function selectSource(source) {
  videoSelectBtn.innerText = source.name;

  const constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
        chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
      },
    },
  };

  //Create a stream
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

  //Preview the source in a video element
  videoElement.srcObject = stream;
  videoElement.play();

  //Create the Media Recorder
  const options = { mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9' };
  mediaRecorder = new mediaRecorder(stream, options);

  //Register Event Handlers
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleAvailableData;
  mediaRecorder.onstop = handleStop;
}

async function handleAvailableData(e) {
  console.log('Video data available');
  recordedChunks.push(e.data);
}

//Save video on stop
async function handleStop(e) {
  const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
    type: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9',
  });

  const buffer = Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer());

  const { filePath } = await dialog.showSaveDialog({
      buttonLabel: 'Save Video',
      defaultPath: `vid-${Date.now()}.webm`
  })

  console.log(filePath);

  writeFile(filePath, buffer, () => console.log('Saved Successfully'))
}
```

Comment: Meaning when I am importing the electron module?

Comment: I mean you will remove it from the package.json, then install it with `npm i electron@10.2.0`.

Comment: I tried it and it worked. But anyways I took the package.json and the lock file from [Github](https://github.com/fireship-io/223-electron-screen-recorder). VS code is still not detecting but the code works just fine. Anyways Thanks.

Comment: Great i was able to help